# How to set the first month of the year in java Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

My requirement is I want to get the week number of the year by passing date.

**Rule:**

First month of the year should be February.
Week should start from Saturday to Friday.

**Eg:**

```
02/01/2019 - should return week number as 1
02/02/2019 - should return week number as 2
```

Comment: Write your question clearer. I had to read it several times to understand exactly what you are looking for. Take a look here: [ask]. Check the moment.js lib if you have more requirements for dates. It might be easier to use their lib instead of handling dates with your "bare hands".

Answer (score 2):

It will take me a bit of argumentation to reach a correct solution: If I understand correctly, the first Friday of February is always in week 1. Week 1 begins 6 days before. If we imagine a “week 0” beginning another 7 days earlier, then the week number for a day will always be the number of whole weeks since the beginning of this “week 0” 13 days before the first Friday in February. We can calculate that.

```
public static int getWeekNumber(LocalDate date) {
    int year = date.getYear();
    if (date.getMonth().equals(Month.JANUARY)) {
        // calculate from February in previous year
        year--;
    }

    LocalDate imaginaryWeek0Start = LocalDate.of(year, Month.FEBRUARY, 1)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY))
            .minusDays(13);

    long weekNo = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(imaginaryWeek0Start, date);

    return Math.toIntExact(weekNo);
}
```

Let’s try it out with the two example dates from your question:

```
    System.out.println(getWeekNumber(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 1)));
    System.out.println(getWeekNumber(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 2)));
```

This printed:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> ```

In case you intended to use the `Calendar` class, I am deliberately not doing that. That class is both poorly designed and long outdated. Instead I recommend `LocalDate` and other classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.